# Why the String value only get one string in StartCommand in Service for Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am trying to send String in Fragment to Service like the following code:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{


    public final static String EXTRA_STATUS = "";
    public final static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "";
    public final static String EXTRA_NAME = "";

    Intent Intent = new Intent(getActivity() , Alarm.class);
    Intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STATUS, "1");
    Intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, "2");
    Intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, "3");

    getActivity().startService(Intent);
```

But in the `StartCommand` of `Service`. It only get the last string I have set to `intent`.

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("AlarmDialog", "AlarmDialog!!! address = " + intent.getStringExtra(PlaceholderFragment.EXTRA_ADDRESS));
        Log.i("AlarmDialog", "AlarmDialog!!! name = " + intent.getStringExtra(PlaceholderFragment.EXTRA_NAME));
        Log.i("AlarmDialog", "AlarmDialog!!! status = " +intent.getStringExtra(PlaceholderFragment.EXTRA_STATUS)) ;


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

In the Service , the log show:

```
AlarmDialog!!! address = 3
AlarmDialog!!! name= 3
AlarmDialog!!! status = 3
```

Dis I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: once check your variable names EXTRA_STATUS,EXTRA_ADDRESS equal to EXTRA_NAME..

Comment: @kalyanpvs Excuse me , what do you mean ? I define the three variable like the content , they didn't equal to each other.

Comment: they are all empty strings means they are all equal..so change to different names for each variable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public final static String EXTRA_STATUS = "";
    public final static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "";
    public final static String EXTRA_NAME = "";
```

change to

```
 public final static String EXTRA_STATUS = "status";
    public final static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "address";
    public final static String EXTRA_NAME = "name";
```

As its empty string last value which is 3 gets stamped. And is seen in all cases the same